# MySQL insert ISO8601 Datetime format

Tags: mysql, sql, iso

I am having trouble with inserting ISO8601 Datetime format into my MySQL database.

I would like to insert ISO format (i.e. **yyyymmddThhmmss+|-hhmm**) into my database table, DATETIME column.

When I try to insert I got problem with:

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to
>   the database. Executing: UPDATE `db`.`orders` SET
>   `date`='20080915T155300+0500' WHERE `id`='1';
>
> ERROR 1292: 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '20080915T155300+0500' for
>   column 'date' at row 1 SQL Statement: UPDATE `db`.`orders` SET
>   `date`='20080915T155300+0500' WHERE `id`='1'

Is there any way that I can save datetimes with this format into MySQL?

Comment: "Is there any way that I can save datetimes with this format into MySQL?" No there isn't a native way.. think you should have the datetime column and time zone column... that way you can calculate the datetime with the timezone on the fly with CONVERT_TZ when selecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has rather arcane support for time zones.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
select convert_tz(str_to_date(left(val, 15), '%Y%m%dT%H%i%s'), '+00:00', insert(right(val, 5), 4, 0, ':'))
from (select '20080915T155300+0500' as val) x
```

Comment: I would need to retrieve inserted datetime with timezone, too. Do you think this way I could revert inserted value (with timezone) and retrieve it, because I see it only converts hours based on +HH:mm (timezone) and insertes '2008-09-15 20:53:00' ?

Comment: @ldragicevic . . . You can swap the two arguments to get the opposite behavior.