# How to insert date ISO 8601 on table?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, timestamp, iso8601

I want to put this format data on my table: `2018-12-04T13:05:00-00:00`

This should be done with a query:

```
$uPqr = $conn->query("UPDATE table SET dateModified = "the date goes here" WHERE id = 25");
```

I don't want to write the date on the query, i want to know if there's a function like `NOW()` or `time()` that do it automatically.

Comment: What is table.dateModified field data type?

Comment: @ZekiGumus `datetime`

Comment: I believe this link can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264218/mysql-insert-iso8601-datetime-format

Comment: @ZekiGumus Did you saw my edit?

Comment: ISO 8601 is presumably what you mean:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the current time -- on the server -- then  just use `now()`:

```
$uPqr = $conn->query("UPDATE table SET dateModified = now() WHERE id = 25");
```

Comment: this won't give the format `2018-12-04T13:05:00-00:00`

Comment: @515948453225 . . . `dateModified` should be a date/time data type.  That uses an internal format.  What this does do is set the value to the current time when it is called.